# How to display currency symbols in Java other than $ sign?

Tags: java

I am trying to pring out the euro and pound currency sign in Java. Understand that they are not in the ASCII set thus need to use their direct charmap. Found out that pound sign = 00A3 and Euro sign = \20AC. Came up with the following line of code and it still doesn't give me the currency signs. I am new to programming and Java. Thanks for advice.

```
public class currency
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println("$, \u00A3 and \u20AC sign.");
  }
}
```

Comment: What does it give to u? im getting correct currency symbols

Comment: Strings in Java are unicode. Just copy and paste £ and €.

Comment: It prints out as: $, u and C sign.

Comment: The Unicode points look correct. Are you sure it's not a problem with the font you're using? For me, outputting to the console in IDEA shows $ and £ properly, but not €, presumably for this reason.

Comment: Depending on your platform, the console you're println'ing on may not be able to display those symbols. Try redirecting the output to a file, then opening the file in a unicode-aware editor and seeing if they're correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to see the characters properly because of the default encoding at the command prompt. On the English version of Windows, it’s [Cp850](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) and it does not have the Euro symbol. You need to change the setting of your console to display the signs correctly. Check this to find a way to correct your console settings for displaying desired currency symbols:

[http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/wpdos/eurodos.html](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Eem36/wpdos/eurodos.html)

The code works fine on eclipse and the output clearly displays all the three currency sign.

Answer (score -1):

I am getting symbols while running it on eclipse. Screenshot attached for your reference
[image]

If you are trying on command prompt or windows console, make sure it shows Character in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Console need NOT to be UTF 8 for this.

Comment: @user1750115 yes, most likely. See if you can set the console's character encoding to utf-8

Comment: @Junen pls refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272032/java-utf-8-strange-behaviour .

Comment: @Sid Try changing your eclipse encoding to non UTF8. It will still work!

Comment: Hi it is working on netbeans but not on command prompt. Anyway to come around it? Tnks.